# POP and IMAP E-Mail from the same 2010 Outlook

Tags: imap, pop3

I am using Outlook 2010. I normally run two e-mail accounts, one personal, and other business.
both have been POP accounts.  My business e-mail just changed from POP to IMAP. Now I hav one POP and one IMAP. When I sen out my imap, it seams to go through my POP account.  They used to run separate. Help

Comment: Can you share more than this? Maybe some screenshots of your settings or a description of your settings? This isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Don, make a note of the address you're sending from in Outlook. Make sure you change it to the address you want to send from. You can enable the 'from' on the options tab in a new email message.[image]